# How can I read the serial output of STM32F103C8T6 from USB to Serial TTL?

Tags: serial, datalogging, print

I recently bought a STM32F103C8T6 board (blue pill)
I programming to it using the USB to Serial TTL I bought (CP2102).

I'm still taking very first steps and trying to figure out how to operate the component.
I was able to burn a basic script to STM32F103C8T6 that causes the P13(LED) to blink.

Now I'm trying to add basic printing that I can see over the serial interface
Which I am already connected to (CP2102).

Here's what my code looks like:

```
void setup() {
// initialize digital pin PC13 as an output.
pinMode(PC13, OUTPUT);
Serial.print("finish setup function \r\n"); // try to print something using serial
}

void loop() { 
digitalWrite(PC13, HIGH);
delay(500);

digitalWrite(PC13, LOW);
delay(500);

Serial.print("loop throgh loop function \r\n"); // try to print something using serial
}
```

Everything is compiled and loaded fine (I work through ARDUINO IDE), but it is not clear to me where I can see these prints.

I tried to see them in Tools-> serial monitor (in the arduino ide tool)
But I didn't see any printing ...

(I know that my code got loaded successfully because I play with the speed of the LED blinks and I see that it is responding to the change at the speed of the flicker).

It feels like it's a really stupid question but where can I see my prints?

Comment: Do you need to initialize the serial interface? That's normally done for Arduino sketches.

Comment: You miss-spelled the word 'throgh'. It should be 'through'. If it is a command it MUST have correct spelling.

Comment: thank you @Sparky256 it's not a command , i simply try to print this sentence

Comment: thank you @ElliotAlderson what i need to initialized and how? can you please give me some basics examples of this?

Comment: Look for some sample code that uses the serial interface. There are many, many examples available and some are included with the Arduino IDE. I'll admit it's not clear to me what programming environment you are using.

Comment: First you must study the documentation of the Arduino port you are using to find out which hardware UART/pins Serial refers to, or if it actually refers to a virtual channel through the stm32's USB port.  Only you know *which* port of Arduino to the stm32 you are using, so only you can do that.